# How to repeat local notification if user dismisses or ignores first one?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, notifications, uilocalnotification

I am developing an alarm app using Swift. While the app is in background, I want to keep repeating local notifications (scheduled by user) if user ignores or dismisses first notification without taking any action on it. How can I achieve this? I have set Snooze & Stop actions on notification and can identify if user takes action on any of these. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the solution by reading many articles online as well discussing with other fellow iOS developers and the only solution would be to schedule repeat notifications after interval of 30 sec with a hope that user will eventually take action on it. Once the user taps on any action we can identify the identifier and continue with our logic. I hope this helps many developers looking for an answer to similar question.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this out

1. Setup a unique ID for your local Notifications
2. when the local notification is fired based on your logic
3. keep track of the notification ID which you fired
4. In your `application:handleActionWithIdentifier:forLocalNotification:completionHandler`
   check the ID of that notification
5. This way you that notification was dismissed and hence you could trigger it again later

Comment: But using this I will get identifier information only if user takes action on notification. If user does not tap on any action then I will not get any information here.

Comment: Right, apple does not provide any callback if the notification is dismissed , Apple intentionally makes this hard because the user has explicitly indicated they do not want to interact with your notification.So the hack would be to put in a check to identify which notification were fired but were dismissed by the user, when ever your app enters foreground or gets launched again.

Comment: I need to keep on firing notifications before user takes any action or app enters foreground otherwise alarm app will lose its functionality. Can you suggest any other logic?

Comment: Without any call backs in this case, i feel its a road block

Comment: But I have seen many alarm apps in App Store that does it without fail.

Comment: Will hae to dig deeper then, will get back to you in case I find some thing of value

Comment: This link has some useful points https://oleb.net/blog/2014/02/alarm-clock-apps-ios/ 
See if it could be of any help

Comment: Thanks for the link! I have already gone through it but it does not tell about logic for repeat notifications.